# Basic unittest TestCase

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have written the below code to test a basic unittest case for learning. When I execute the below code. I do not get any output. Could someone let me know what could be issue.

```
import unittest
  class test123(unittest.TestCase):

    def test1(self):
      print "test1"

 if __name__ == "main":
 x=test123()
 x.test1()
 unittest.main()
```

Comment: It should be `if __name__ == "__main__":` and all you have to do is call `unittest.main()`. You don't need to instantiate your class. The `unittest.main()` handles everything for you. Revise the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

your code should look like this:

```
import unittest

class test123(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        print "test1"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

hence it is name and main with two underscores at the start and end, when you change it and run it with your code then you will get an error with using:

```
x = test123()
x.test1()

ValueError: no such test method in <class '__main__.test123'>: runTest
```

Answer (score 1):

In your test you need two things:

1. Define your test function with 'test'
2. You need a expected result

test.py

```
import unittest

class TestHello(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_hello(self):  # Your test function usually need define her name with test
        str_hello = 'hello'
        self.assertEqual(str_hello, 'hello') # you need return a expected result

    def test_split(self):
        str_hello = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(str_hello.split(), ['hello', 'world'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

for execute use:

```
python -m unittest test
```

out:

```
stackoverflow$ python -m unittest test
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
class weblogin(unittest.TestCase):
 def open_fb(self):
  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
  email_field=driver.find_element_by_id("email")
  email_field.send_keys("test123@gmail.com")
  pass_field=driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
  pass_field.send_keys("test123")
  pass_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 unittest.main()